# How to pass Input to handle() and how to call handle() of LaunchRequestHandler in alexa SDK V2 for Java?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am migrating to ASK SDK v2 for Java, where in the SDK v2, each `onLaunch`, `onSessionEnded`, and `ontIntent` case is separated out into a different handler.

#### Question:

How to pass my input to `handle(HandlerInput input)` of `LaunchRequestHandler` and how to call `handle(HandlerInput input)` of `LaunchRequestHandler` from my code?

Also, in V2 `SpeechletRequestEnvelope` class has been removed, so how to create `requestEnvelope` to get `Request` and `Session` details ?

```
public class LaunchRequestHandler implements RequestHandler {
  @Override
  public boolean canHandle(HandlerInput input) {
    return input.matches(Predicates.requestType(LaunchRequest.class));
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<Response> handle(HandlerInput input) {
  String speechText = "Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say hello";
    return input.getResponseBuilder()
        .withSpeech(inputString)
        .withSimpleCard("HelloWorld", inputString)
        .withReprompt(inputString)
        .build();
  }
}
```

Calling Place :

```
String body = myO ject.getAdditionalProperties().get("request").toString();
byte[] myRequest = URLDecoder.decode(body, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()).getBytes();
```

How to pass `myRequest` to `handle()` of `LaunchRequestHandler` and how to call the same `handle()` method?

Answer (score 0):

for you second question related to the Request and Session details

```
public ResponseEntity<String> handleAlexaRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {

    RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope;
    ServletRequest servletRequest;

    byte[] serializedRequestEnvelope;

    try {
        serializedRequestEnvelope = IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getInputStream());
        RequestEnvelope deserializedRequestEnvelope = this.serializer.deserialize(new String(serializedRequestEnvelope, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), RequestEnvelope.class);

        servletRequest = new ServletRequest(request,serializedRequestEnvelope,deserializedRequestEnvelope);

        requestEnvelope = verifier.verify(alexaHttpRequest);

    }


    requestEnvelope.getRequest();
    requestEnvelope.getSession()
```